Eigenvalue of linear map on finitely generated torsionfree module is integral?
Let $R$ be a Noetherian integral domain and $Q$ be the field of fractions of $R$. Let $L$ be a finite field extension of $Q$. Let $S$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $L$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated torsionfree $R$-module and $f: M\to M$ an $R$-linear map. Let $\alpha\in L$ be an eigenvalue of $f\otimes_R L: M\otimes_R L\to M\otimes_R L$. Then, is it true that $\alpha \in S$?
Thoughts: By hypothesis, $f\otimes_R L - \alpha.id_{M\otimes_R L}$ has a nonzero kernel ... I don't know where to go from here ... please help.

The statement is certainly true if $M$ is free. Then $f$ is represented by a matrix over $R$ and $\alpha$ is a zero of the characteristic polynomial of $f$.

The statement is true.
As $M$ is finitely generated, there is a finitely generated free module $F \cong R^n$ and a surjective homomorphism $p \colon F \to M$. Since $F$ is projective, there exists a homomorphism $\tilde f \colon F \to F$ such that $p \circ \tilde f = f \circ p$, i.e. $\tilde f$ is a lift of $f$. Let $P \in R[T]$ be the characteristic polynomial of $\tilde f$ on $F$. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $P(\tilde f) = 0$, which also implies $P(f) = 0$ and $P(f \otimes L) = 0$. Now if $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $f \otimes L$, then also $P(\alpha) = 0$. This proves the claim as $P$ is a monic polynomial over $R$.

Thank you for your answer ... I've mostly understood it, except possibly one point ... why is $P(\alpha)=0$ if $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $f\otimes L$?

Ah, is this because $P(f \otimes L)=0$ implies the characteristic polynomial of $f\otimes L$ must divide $P(T)$? Also, did torsionfree ness of $M$ or $L$ being finite extension of $Q$ needed to be used anywhere? Is this true for any finitely generated $M$ and any field extension $L$ of $Q$?

Actually, could you please explain why $P(f \otimes L)=0$?

For $P(\alpha) = 0$: If $f$ is a linear map and $f(v) = \alpha v$, then you can check that $P(f)(v) = P(\alpha) v$ for all polynomials $P$. If $P(f)=0$, then we get $P(\alpha) v = 0$. If $v$ is non-zero, then $P(\alpha) = 0$.
For torsion-freeness: It is not necessary. It doesn't matter anyway, because base changing to a field kills all torsion.

$\DeclareMathOperator{id}{id}$ For $P(f\otimes L)$: This is just calculation. First, note $(f\otimes L)^n = (f \otimes \id_L)^n = f^n \otimes \id_L^n = f^n \otimes \id_L$. Then for $P = \sum a_iT^i$, we have $P(f \otimes L) = \sum a_i (f\otimes L)^i = \sum a_i (f^i \otimes \id_L) = (\sum a_if^i) \otimes \id_L = P(\alpha) \otimes L = 0$.
